# "Restoring previously installed packages" never ends

Tags: upgrade, 11.10, live-usb

I'm upgrading Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 via a liveusb. It has been "restoring previously installed packages" for about 1h 30 mins. Is it normal to take so much time? Could I do something to improve speed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal that the upgrade take a long time. And no, there is nothing you can do to improve speed.

Check that there is no dialog waiting a answer for you that could stop the process, if there is not you should at least wait 3 hours before admitting that there is a problem.

If you try to stop the process now your system will be unusable.